# Drupal 7 Custom Search Result Page

Tags: theming, search

I am trying to create a custom page that display my resuslts which I receive after I search for a post.

I am having no luck, I am a total begginer in drupal 7, I googled and looked around here but I did not quite understood what I have to do.

What I tried:

```
function **themename**_preprocess_search_results(&$variables) {
  $variables['search_results'] = '';
  if (!empty($variables['module'])) {
    $variables['module'] = check_plain($variables['module']);
  }
  foreach ($variables['results'] as $result) {
    $variables['search_results'] .= theme('search_result', array('result' => $result, 'module' => $variables['module']));
  }
  $variables['pager'] = theme('pager', array('tags' => NULL));
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'search_results__' . $variables['module'];
}
```

1. Creating a search-results.tpl.php ( did not work )
2. The only module I have installed for search is the default search module.

Nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: _search-results.tpl.php_ should be _search--results.tpl.php_. Two dashes, not one

Answer (score -1):

You are just processing the search results in your function but haven;t handled the output. Change the tpl.php to display the variables from your function rather than from the default search function.

Comment: `$variables['search_results']` does contain the output. It is used from the template file. I am not sure what you mean by _but haven't handled the output_. May you make that clearer?